# jQuery click and call function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, dc.js

I use d3.js and dc.leaflet.js to draw cluster map and markers map.
".cluster(true)" or ".cluster(false)" can change the map style.

```
var MKmarker = dc_leaflet.markerChart("#map")
    function drawmap(MapTypeBoolean) {
      MKmarker
        .dimension(geoDim)
        .group(geoGroup)
        .center([23.5, 121])
        .zoom(7)
        .cluster(MapTypeBoolean)//MapTypeBoolean true = cluster map / false = marker map
        .renderPopup(false)
        .filterByArea(true);
    };
drawmap(true); // The default is cluster map
```

I set two buttons to switch the map by calling `drawmap` function again with different Boolean, but they don't work.

```
$('.marker').click(function() {
    $('.cluster').addClass('btn-default');
    $('.cluster').removeClass('btn-info');
    $(this).removeClass('btn-default');
    $(this).addClass('btn-info');
    drawmap(false); // When the 'marker'button is clicked, it should call drawmap function again with 'false'. ->But it doesn't work.
});
```

Here is my codepen. https://codepen.io/skysky888/pen/bqmpEe

Thank you~

Comment: where is the `.marker` in your code? I don't see it!

Comment: It's in line 17 in HTML. Thank you~

Comment: I got an error: L.mapbox is undefined

Are you missing a reference somewhere?

Comment: I know the function is being called I placed some logs there!

Comment: @Korgrue I find that I add an useless JavaScript file(keen.dashboard.js). It causes the error.

Comment: I create two overlapping divs and use show() hide() functions to achieve the result I want. Thank you for helping. ^_^